# Is A an amenable $C^{*}$-algebra?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be $C^{*}$-algebra. Suppose that, for any $\epsilon > 0$ and finite subset $F \subset A$, there are an amenable $C^{*}$-subalgebra $B \subset A$, contractive completely positive linear maps $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ and $L: B \rightarrow A$ such that $id ~{\approx}{\epsilon} ~L \circ \phi$ on $F$. Then is $A$ an amenable $C^{*}$-algebra?

I would be thankful if you help me out.

Comment: This follows immediately from the fact that a $C^\ast$-algebra is amenable if and only if it has the completely positive approximation property.

Comment: @JamieGabe Yes, you are completely right. I haven't CP app. property in my mind. Thanks for your help.